# Unable to configure ISAPI Redirector with Tomcat 10 and IIS 10 using anonymous authentication

Tags: tomcat, iis, isapi

I am trying to configure Tomcat ISAPI for Tomcat 10 on IIS 10 with anonymous authentication. I have added local ISAPI Filter, created jakarta application, granted execute permission to ISAPI module, and added .jsp mime type at site level.  Updated connector port settings in Tomcat server.xml to

The redirect only works if I enable Windows Authentication. I need it working for anonymous authentication. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: I want to know how you configure Tomcat to work with IIS. You can enable [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) when using anonymous authentication. Failed request tracing will log the process of handling request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. In Windows 2019, IIS 10 Anonymous user credentials are set to IUSR by default. This needs to be changed to Application Pool. The done under Authentication by right-clicking on Anonymous Authentication and selecting Edit.